How to connect two Ubuntu 24.04 hosts over ad-hoc Ethernet?
I am connecting a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 running Ubuntu 24.04 to a laptop (also running Ubuntu 24.04) over an ethernet patch cable. There is no router/managed switch between the devices. Ideally, the Pi would be assigned a static IP when it connects, so the laptop could SSH into the Pi.
Right now I am configuring a static IP address on the Pi with this /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
# Settings for static ip
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            addresses:
              - 192.168.1.2/24
            routes:
              - to: default
                via: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 192.168.1.1]
# Settings for dhcp below
#            dhcp4: true
#            optional: true
    version: 2

On the laptop, I have IPv4 to Manual with an address of 192.168.2.1, mask of 255.255.255.0, and gateway of 192.168.2.2.
Right now I get ping: connect: Network is unreachable when pinging any IP address from the laptop.
Is this the correct way to connect these hosts? Thanks!

Is there a reason both devices are on separate subnets? Have you tried configuring them on the same subnet?

If Raspberry ethernet is 192.168.1.2/24, Laptop should be 192.168.1.3/24. not 192.168.2.1/24

When connecting two computers directly for file sharing or peer-to-peer networking, a crossover cable is required. This is because both computers function as end devices and would require a crossover cable to establish a direct connection.

If you don't have a switch between the two devices, the correct way is to use an Ethernet crossover cable.  A regular Ethernet cable won't work. Here's a good explanation of the difference
https://community.fs.com/article/patch-cable-vs-crossover-cable.html

You can do a direct Ethernet to Ethernet connection - most 'crossover' cable needs are fixed at the negotiation level of the link.  I've done this with two computers before (RPi and my laptop on a direct Ethernet link).  The need for "crossover cables" is much more reduced in modern network.

My understanding was that crossover cables aren't necessary with most modern devices, which detect the correct TX/RX based on what the other side is using (https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34797/do-straight-though-and-crossover-still-have-any-play-in-todays-business).
